# Python script not continuing after calling subprocess

Tags: java, python, subprocess

I have a python script calling a java file with the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
java_cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'bin/stuff/:lib/asm-all-3.3.jar:lib/jdom.jar',
      'ch.idsia.scenarios.Main']
subprocess.call(java_cmd, shell=False)
print "Hello world"
```

This works correctly, and the java file then waits for the python script to continue and connect a socket, as I want it to. But the python script doesn't continue. Why not? I know it doesn't because the `print` statement never executes.

Everything runs as expected when I manually run the java file from Eclipse and then execute the python script from the command line.
I also tried with `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `subprocess.call()`, with no difference in the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @KSFT; `subprocess.call()` doesn't return until the command finishes, but `subprocess.Popen()` does. So I made the call with `subprocess.Popen()` and then `time.sleep(0.5)`. Having the python script wait 0.5 seconds allows the java file enough time to open and initialize the socket connections.

Answer (score 1):

[`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) doesn't return until the command it runs finishes. You can use [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) to run something else at the same time.