# Starting VLC stops the rest of a python script

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, vlc

I am experimenting with different python scripts to run videos and I am encountering a strange error, anytime I start vlc, the rest of the script stops executing.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import time
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["vlc", "myVideo.mp4", "-f", "-L", "--no-audio", "&"])

print("I never print")

time.sleep(5)
subprocess.call(["killall", "-9", "vlc"])
print("I never print either!")
```

Comment: Check if subprocess.call returns immediately or waits for the called process to end. It could be that it waits for the process to exit and then return.

Comment: Almost, but not 100% duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29464145/2988730

Comment: @naaz. The latter of course :) I didn't close as dupe because OP tried with `&`

Comment: @MadPhysicist That did the trick, if you want to add subprocess.Popen() as the correct answer, I am happy to give you a shiny green check.

Comment: It's counter productive, though not explicitly forbidden, to place semicolons at the end of lines in Python.

Comment: @Code2Empower. I've added enough detail to hopefully earn that check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list that you pass to the `subprocess` functions is interpreted as `argv` for the program. Since `shell=False` by default, no interpretation is done on the arguments. Specifically, `&` is passed as the last argument to `vlc`, and does not start a background process.

To start a background process, call `Popen` directly. `call` will always wait for the subprocess to complete, so it's not what you want.